# Google App Engine Query Limit and Timeout

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using App Engine to build a site, and now I worry about the 30 seconds Time per request limit.

For example, I have more than 10,000 members or even more, and I do the following:

```
# class Member(db.Model): ...
# Start a query 
result = Member.all().filter('username =','example').filter('password = ','123456').get()
#Will this time out?
result = Member.all().order('joindate').fetch(10)
#Will this time out?
```

I wonder, will these queries work without Timeout? I am afraid the `.all().filter().order()` will timeout.

Is there some more secure way to do that when the number of members are too large?

**By the way, will this 30 secs per request limit apply when I upload a video to the app engine Blobstore? The max single file size for Blobstore is 2GB, and if I upload via an HTML form, it may take hours. Will the 30 secs per request limit apply?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I really, really hope you're not storing user passwords in plaintext in the datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be short:

1. the first two fetch query will be completed within 1 second. Actually, it should be completed within several hundreds of ms or dozens of ms.
2. the '.all().filter().order()' has not tried to fetch any data at all, so don't worry about the time.